# Magento 2 - No shipping rates when creating order programmatically leads to "The shipping method is missing"

Tags: magento2.3

I am developing a module which programmatically submits an order.

In the store configuration I have enabled both free shipping and table rates shipping methods.

When I get the shipping methods for the quote using a block like below I get all shipping methods (flat rate, free, table) and can retrieve their cost.

```
$methods = Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement->estimateByExtendedAddress($quote->getId(), 
$quote->getShippingAddress());
```

But when I try to submit the quote unless I add to the quote address rates for each method the order submission fails with the subject error, unless the method is `flat rate`. So I use a snippet like below for each quote submit call.

```
public function setShippingRates(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote)
{
    $methods = (get methods as above);
    foreach ($methods as $method) {
        $methodId = "{$method->getCarrierCode()}_{$method->getMethodCode()}";
        $rate = Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateFactory->create()
                ->setCode($methodId)
                ->setPrice($method->getAmount());    
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->addShippingRate($rate);
    }
}
```

Is this expected?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I in my case the issue is that I had to first save the quote and then collect rates like so

```
Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface->save($this->quote);
$this->quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates();
```

Maybe it has to do with the way that I create the quote.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try this code :

```
 // set shipping method
$shippingAddress=$quote->getShippingAddress();
$shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                ->collectShippingRates()
                ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate'); //please verify flat rate shipping must be enable
        
$quote->setInventoryProcessed(false); //decrease item stock equal to qty
$quote->save(); //quote save
```

Comment: Thanks Dhiren, I am already setting the shipping method but not always to flat rate, if the quote is eligible for free shipping I set it to `freeshipping_freeshipping`. Should I always set it to `flat rate` ?

Comment: No, you need to just set the proper shipping method code there.

Comment: so since I set the shipping method do I also need to create and set the rate as well? For flat rate method the rate is found but for all others (free, table) it isn't, unless I set it, leading to "shipping method is missing".

Comment: First confirm that all are enable and setup properly. rest will work as it is.

Comment: I would assume they are correctly set because when a quote is eligible for free shipping for example I get the method when I query shipping methods for the quote address. But at the same time there is no rate for this method.